# Apache on mac OS X snow leopard doesn't seem to run

Tags: macos, apache

I have mac OS X and would like the built-in apache webserver to run. So I open up "System Preferences", click on "Sharing" and enable "Web sharing". Web server starts (apparently) and the system displays two links which I can use. One is just my ip and the other is my ip/username. Both links just result in "no connection" error in the browser. It doesn't appear to reach apache at all, like apache isn't running.

So I open up terminal and enter:

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

no apache process found. I then try the following command:

```
netstat -ln | grep ':80 ' | grep 'LISTEN'
```

and nothing is returned. So it appears apache isn't running.

Why would the system preference tell me otherwise? And how can I fix it?

Comment: by default on osx apache runs under root with the name process httpd

Comment: also you can use `top` from terminal to get a table of active processes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use Terminal (/Applications/Utilities), and then try to start apache from the command line.

Try this to help debug:

```
sudo bash -x /usr/sbin/apachectl -k start
```

when it is dying silently. Also, check the `error_log` at:

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log
```

You can use TextEdit for the `error_log`, if you feel more comfortable with a GUI text editor.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file /private/var/log/apache2/error_log.
Unable to open logs
+ ERROR=1
+ exit 1

Comment: Alright! So i just created the missing apache2 directory in /var/log/ and then it started working. Why that directory was missing is weird, but maybe i shouldn't care?

Comment: I agree. That seems like something the default install should have handled. Were there any errors during the OS installation?

Answer (score 0):

Have had similar problem on a (by now rather old) Macbook still running SL.

Looking at the log, per previous answer, revealed an error loading mod_hfs_apple.so from /usr/libexec/apache2. Checking this, there was no such file in that folder. I copied the file from my other Mac (running Lion, not Snow Leopard) and hey presto the sudo restart command got the server going.